# Recommendations for affordable and reliable Drupal theme designer

Tags: css, javascript, drupal, theme, website-design

Can anyone recommend an affordable and reliable Drupal theme designer, who can take a concept and produce a Drupal 6.19-compliant theme?

The backend functionality and structure of the web site is complete, I'm purely looking for someone who can create a Drupal theme from scratch, based on a design concept.

Thanks in advance,

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know a brilliant designer with great design skills and a portfolio you can look over. 
I didn't post a link originally because I wanted to ask his permission to do so and ask whether he was available. If you want to see some of his portfolio on-line you can see it at http://www.designbyspirit.com.

I'd rather recommend someone I know and admire personally rather than a random website or people I don't know really anything about in terms of honesty and integrity. I don't get any financial benefit from recommending him, I just admire his skills and his work ethic.

If you like his designs you could easily find someone in the Drupal.org community to do a theme conversion from an original design. Drupal is not only a cool system but a great community and there are a lot of good people at Drupal.org who would be willing to help you out in the forums or be available for hire. See http://drupal.org/node/995766

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've created a Zen sub-theme, which I am styling at the moment. I may/may not be in touch - depending how I get on! But if I do outsource the work, I'll certainly bear you in mind.

Comment: You're welcome, Mike. Check out the Fusion theme at http://drupal.org/project/fusion if you want a flexible starter theme that doesn't require as much CSS styling work as Zen. I use it for most of my theme work now. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

http://themeforest.net/category/misc/drupal

Comment: You can buy themes or better yet direct message the designers on the site.  Many take freelance work.